# How to remove default date in mvc4 textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one Textbox in mvc4 application as below.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.dateofAction, ViewBag.filterdateTime as string,  new { @id = "dateofAction", @placeholder = "Date Of Action", @class = "txtBox form-control calender validate[required]" })
```

I am using jquery calender for this textbox.

```
 $(document).on('focus', '.calender', function(){
         $(this).datepicker({

             dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
             showOn: 'button',
             buttonImage: '/images/icondate.png',
             buttonImageOnly: true
        })
            });
```

This is my model

```
 [DisplayName("dateofAction")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime dateofAction { get; set; }
```

I am facing problem when first time page loads default date `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` is displaying in textbox. Actually i want to show placeholder value.

May i know why i am not able to get placeholder value?

Comment: Make you property nullable - `public DateTime? dateofAction { get; set; }` (and **do not** set the `value` attribute!)

Comment: Thanks stephen. Works like charm

Comment: And remove your `$(document).on('focus', '.calender', function(){` and replace it with just `$('#dateofAction').datapicker({ ... });` and remove `new { @id = "dateofAction" }` (it already has that `id`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke What if user don't wont to use nullable date time? and if we use value attribute then does it affect to anything else?

Comment: Thanks stephen. I removed and made changes. Thanks a lot. Can you put answers please

Comment: @Div, Whats it got to do with the user. OP wants an empty value initially so that the placeholder is displayed - therefore the property must be `nullable` (and it can be decorated with `[Required]` if a value must be submitted)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I just want to know, how to display an empty value without making `nullable` date time

Comment: @Div, You cant and expect to get correct 2-way model binding (you never set the `value` attribute)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, OK, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to display an empty textbox with the placeholder, you need to make your property nullable. If also want a date to be selected, then you can also decorate the property with the `[Required]` attribute.

Note also that your `[DisplayFormat]` is unnecessary and is ignoted by the `TextBoxFor()` method. You should also be using the `[Display]` attribute, not `[DisplayName]` Your property should be

```
[Display(Name= "Date of Action")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a date")]
public DateTime? dateofAction { get; set; }
```

Then in the view your code should be just

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.dateofAction, new { @placeholder = "Date Of Action", @class = "txtBox form-control calender validate[required]" })
```

and your datepicker plugin should be initialize when the DOM is rendered, not each time its focused

```
$('#dateofAction').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    ....
})
```

Comment: Yes this is what i need. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

the DateTime is struct and value. when you pass model to view "dateofAction" has default value. two way for this challenge:

1. make dateofAction as nullable.
2. set dateofAction to DateTime.Now when create model.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve this problem.

1. set the entity Nullable by adding "?" next to the datatype of entity
   like  `public DateTime? dateofAction { get; set; }`
2. If you don't want to make the entity Nullable the you can add this code in the view "view.cshtml"

> ```
> var variableName = 
>     Model.Value.ToString("d") == default(DateTime).ToString("d") ? "" :
>     Model.Value.ToString("d");
> ```

in this case Model.Value.ToString("d"); is replaced by Model.dateofAction.ToString("d");

Use "variableName" this as value in your input field

in ToString("d"), "d" is string formatter
Learn more about string formatting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types)